# ANT issue on Mac

Tags: ant, mac-os-x

I'm not even tryin to do a deploy.  All I am doing is a retrieve.  No deploy yet.

The error is:

> Failed to send request to https://${sffrom.serverurl}/services/Soap/u/43.0

Ant in verbose mode shows me this:

> Property "sffrom.username" has not been set
>   Property "sffrom.password" has not been set
>   Property "sffrom.serverurl" has not been set

My build properties looks like this.

```
# build.properties
#
# Specify the login credentials for the desired Salesforce organization
sffrom.username = keith.reedy@email.com.sandboxname
sffrom.password = passowrdANDtoken
sffrom.serverurl = https://test.salesforce.com
# 
# 
sfto.username = keith.reedy@email.com
sfto.password = prodpasswordandtoken
sfto.serverurl = https://login.salesforce.com
#
```

My build.xml has:

```
<property file="build.properties "/>
```

This line in my build.xml fails

```
<sf:retrieve username="${sffrom.username}" password="${sffrom.password}" serverurl="${sffrom.serverurl}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" unpackaged="package.xml"/>
```

If I replace those `${property setting}` items with hard coded URL, email, and pass+token, it works.  It just seems the Mac isn't pulling in the `build.properties`.

Again, I used to have this working on windows.  New company uses Macs and it isn't working.

Comment: Thanks David.  first post...took me a few minutes to work out the formatting.  :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the issue, but you have a spurious space in your `<property file="" />` tag.

Comment: not sure if I should cry or scream.  that was it.  I was reading it as properties" />.  My eyes just put the space in the correct space.  Your eyes...are keener.  Thank you!

Comment: Nothing messes up cross-OS scripting like spaces and path separators.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this as an answer to show the question's resolved:

There is an extra space in the `file` attribute in the `property` tag:

```
<property file="build.properties "/>
```

which results in the properties file not being found on the Mac.